# What is the Time Complexity of the Matrix Exponential?

Tags: time-complexity, approximation, matrices

While trying to compute the Matrix Exponential of an `nxn` array I decided to take advantage of a Python function called `scipy.linalg.expm()`.

According to the [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.17.1/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.expm.html), this function adopts the [Pade' Approximant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pad%C3%A9_approximant) to perform a calculation that, otherwise, is said to require a lot of resources and is still a matter of discussion in the mathematics community.

The documentation itself references a work by Al-Mohy and Higham ([doi: 10.1137/04061101X](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/04061101X)), in which I was not able to find any indication regarding the Time Complexity (either T or Theta would work) of this procedure.

Has anyone come across the same problem? What is your suggestion for determining said Time Complexity?

Comment: Do you want exact outputs or approximate outputs? ​ If exact, then how simplified must the entries be? ​ If approximate, then in what sense? ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: Uh...well if I understand what you say, the Pade approximation itself returns approximated values. If I don't understand, well, could you be more specific?

Comment: Should the approximations be ​ ​ ​ [absolute](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximation_error#Formal_Definition) , ​ entrywise [relative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximation_error#Uses_of_relative_error) , relative to the [operator norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_norm) , the algorithm's choice of [absolute / reactive to the operator norm] , simultaneously absolute and relative to the operator norm , entrywise in both absolute and relative error , the algorithm chooses absolute or relative for each entry ​ ​ ​ or something else? ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: let's go with absolute